# How do I tell a Dojo 1.6 Tree connected to a JsonRest to have "forest" behaviour?

Tags: tree, dojo

As the question says.  I'm using a JsonRest object in Dojo 1.6 and would like to have the Tree that is listening through it have forest (rather than singular tree) behaviour.

Examples on the site don't seem to clearly indicate how I can trigger this behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a dijit.tree.ForestStoreModel. See http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dijit/tree/ForestStoreModel.html

You may also need to use a dojo.store.DataStore. It serves as an adapter for now because dijit widgets are still (at least in 1.6) made for using dojo.data APIs rather than dojo.store. See the section called "Working with existing widgets and stores" in [this page](http://dojotoolkit.org/features/1.6/object-store).